# Smooth scrolling effect not working in Mozila and IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

Smooth scrolling effect in JQuery not working in IE & Mozila Browsers, its fine in Chrome browser can any one help on this. iam using this code. some times working in mozila but in IE. please ignore stickit() function. 
Thanks in Advance.

```js
< script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js" > < /script> <
  script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" > < /script>  <
  script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" > < /script> <
  script src = "scroll_110.js" > < /script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add scrollspy to <body>
  $('a').scrollspy({
    target: "a",
    offset: 50
  });

  // Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1200, function() {

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});

// Create a clone of the menu, right next to original.
jquery('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0').css('margin-top', '0').css('z-index', '500').removeClass('original').hide();

scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);


function stickIt() {

  var orgElementPos = jquery('.original').offset();
  orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;

  if (jquery(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {
    // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.

    // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.     
    orgElement = jquery('.original');
    coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
    leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;
    widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
    jquery('.cloned').css('left', leftOrgElement + 'px').css('top', 0).css('width', widthOrgElement).show();
    jquery('.original').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  } else {
    // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
    jquery('.cloned').hide();
    jquery('.original').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }
}
```

```css
#top,
#middle,
#bottom {
  height: 1600px;
  width: 900px;
  background: green;
}

.menu {
  background: #fffff;
  color: #333;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#top">Top</a>
  <a href="scroll_110.html#middle">Middle</a>
  <a href="scroll_110.html#bottom">Bottom</a>
</div>

<div id="top">
  <a href="top"></a>Top</div>
<div id="middle">
  <a href="middle"></a>Middle</div>
<div id="bottom">
  <a href="bottom"></a>Bottom</div>
```

Comment: Please create a working snippet that includes the `HTML` and `CSS` code and demonstrates the problem you're saying you have.

Answer (score 0):

the solution would be to use both html and body in JQ -> `$('html,body').animate`

see below ( i removed the scrollspy code as it's not relevant to this question, but you should keep it )

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add scrollspy to <body>


  // Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1200, function() {

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  border-top: 10px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">Section1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Section2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Section3</a></li>
</ul>
        
<div id ="section1">

</div>
<div id ="section2">

</div>
<div id ="section3">

</div>
```

Comment: @SaiVijay about what IE are you talking ? in my IE11 everything is fine